# Using UiActionSheet in Storyboard?

Tags: storyboard, uiactionsheet

I need to make a button ("Continue"), to open another UiView/Page. I am Very new to developing. Can someone please walk me though this? Thank you, you guys are a big help for me.

Code:

```
- (IBAction)OpenActionSheetButton:(id)sender {


UIActionSheet *actionsheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]initWithTitle:@"There is no going back,     are you sure???" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Continue" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
[actionsheet showInView:self.view];
}

-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
if(buttonIndex == 0)
{
    UIViewController *controller =  [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"storyboardViewIdentifier"];
    //storyboardViewIdentifier is the ViewController identifier you specify in the storyboard

    //PUSH
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
    //Modal
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:Nil];
}
}
```

This is what i did with your code:

```
- (IBAction)OpenActionSheetButton:(id)sender {


UIActionSheet *actionsheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]initWithTitle:@"There is no going back, are you sure???" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Continue" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
[actionsheet showInView:self.view];
}

-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
 if(buttonIndex == 0)
 {
    if(buttonIndex == 0)
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"openView" sender:self];
    UIViewController *controller =  [self.storyboard


    instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"storyboardViewIdentifier"];
    //storyboardViewIdentifier is the ViewController identifier you specify in the storyboard

    //PUSH
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
    //Modal
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:Nil];
}
```

}

Comment: is the uiactionsheet showing up?

Comment: Yes it is :) Just when I click "Continue", it force-closes obviously.

Comment: Why do you need to push view controller and present view controller modally at the same time? You should choose only one.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you perform a presenting segue to bring up your next view controller? Go to your storyboard and create a segue pointing to the new view controller. You need to create a modal segue and name it something unique.

To do this add all the necessary view controllers to your storyboard, then right click on the view controller presenting. Create modal segue presenting.

Then from your code inside you can simply put:

```
 if(buttonIndex == 0)
      [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"openView" sender:self];
```

To dismiss is even easier!

```
   [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for responding. Ok. Tell me if i am doing this right:      I controll-clicked from the view that has the actionsheet and dragged to the view i want to "Continue" button to open. I clcked Model and to the right i typed in the "Identifier" box "YesContinue" as the name. Can you please Explain what you meant by                       "add all the necessary view controllers to your storyboard, then right click on the view controller presenting. Create modal segue presenting."  Do i need to add more viewcontrollers than i already have? Thank you i know i sound very basic but i am :(